# while loop reads same variable from 2 different pthreads but code not running

Tags: c, linux, while-loop, pthreads

I am trying to detect core to core latency in simple memory sharing. My objective is to read a global variable from two different threads. Let's say the variable is x=0 at the beginning. Now one thread will read the value and change the x to 1. Another thread is reading the same variable and as soon as it reads x=1, it makes it 0. I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double getsecs(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1.0e6;
}

int x=0;
//count=0;

void* changetoone(void *arg)
{
    //sched_setaffinity(0);
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        while(x!=1)
        { 
            x=1;
            printf("%d", x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void* changetozero(void *arg){
    //sched_setaffinity(5);
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        while(x!=0)
        { 
            x=0;
            printf("%d", x);
        }
    } 
    return 0;           
} 

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, changetoone, &x);

    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, changetozero, &x);    

    pthread_join(&thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(&thread2, NULL);
}
```

For some reason, the code is not running. I am not familiar with using pthread and I think I made some silly mistakes. Can anybody point out the mistake for me, please?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior, you need _some_ synchronization (at least an atomic).

Comment: Thank you Barmar. My question has 3 parts. (to see how core to core latency varies for different synchronization methods--> a) simple sharing b) with atomic instruction c) with mutex lock. So isn't there any way we can see the performance (round time for the threads to execute) without any synchronization?

Comment: The argument to `pthread_join` should be `thread1`, not `&thread1`. You should have gotten a compiler warning about incompatible types.

Comment: In C you're bound by the C memory model. Your access the `x` race, the compiler isn't required to reload it each time through the loop. (Maybe if you disable all optimizations you'll see something different.)

Comment: Without synchronization it's possible for the second thread to change the variable back to 0 before the first thread does its `printf()`. You should probably add something to the printf so you know which thread it is, like `printf("1 %d\n", x);` in `changetoone()`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `pthread_join` is `pthread_t`, not `pthread_t*`. So you shouldn't use `&` when calling it.

```
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
```

The actual behavior of the program is undefined because of lack of synchronization between the threads when accessing `x`. But this will at least allow the threads to run.

Comment: I fixed it but the code still won't run. If I put the printf's in the threads outside of the while loop I get something like this: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...111111111111111111111111111....0000000000000....1111111111.... 
But I am not sure if that is the output I am expecting. I ultimately want to get the time it takes for a round trip in the 2 threads that will run in 2 different cores.

Comment: When I ran it I got alternating `10101010...`. But as we've said, the results are undefined because you don't have synchronization.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't run for you, it runs for me.

Comment: Did you make any alteration to the code? Also, I am running the code in Ubuntu virtualbox which has only one core.

Comment: No other alterations, but I'm running on a Mac with 4 cores. That will affect the timing, but shouldn't change whether the program runs.